# Мужской и женский род в одном лице

Tags: род

Можно ли употреблять существительное в мужском роде и глагол в женском?

> *Преподаватель опоздала на урок.*

Или, например:

> *Доктор Иванова высказала своё мнение.*

Comment: https://aif.ru/society/education/vrach_on_ili_ona_kak_pravilno Слова "преподаватель" это не касается.

Answer (score 0):

Слова "преподаватель" и "доктор" являются словами *общего рода*. Род глагола в данном случае будет зависеть от контекста.
Такими же словами являются, например, слова *"задира"*, *"сирота"* и т.д.
Слово "преподавательница" является словом женского рода, но его использование не является обязательным.

**ПРАВКА**
Заметил что у слов общего рода есть правило что они должны оканчиваться на -а или -я, иногда -ло, т.е "доктор" - это не общий род.
Но это не запрещает применение женского рода в сочетаниях с "доктор" или "преподаватель" в современном русском языке, т.к. существует значимость фактического значения слова в его роде.
Это правило существовало издавна, но расширилось во времена когда женщины начали становиться равноправными с мужчинами. К примеру суффикс -еньк- используется со словами женского почти всегда, но "Сереженька" это мужской род, потому что это слово указывает на мальчика, а не просто предмет.

Comment: Нет, в словарях везде указан мужской.

Comment: @oleedd спасибо что поправили. действительно так